# How to set the width of columns in tex?

Tags: margins, multicol

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}    

lots of text goes here.

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If I add lots of text, I get two columns, but there is a lot of space left on both sides, i.e. the columns are too narrow. I am trying to make a one page CV. How can I increase the width of the columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`multicol` is only responsible for dividing the text block into columns -- for changing the outer margins resp. the width/height of the text block, you should use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```